# How to filter a nested document in a collection and update a filed?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection called `Jobs`.

```
[
    {
        _id : 1
        content:[
            {
                _id : 1,
                stuff: "A" 
            },
            {
                _id : 2,
                stuff: "B" 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id : 2
        content:[
            {
                _id : 1,
                stuff: "X" 
            },
            {
                _id : 2,
                stuff: "Y" 
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

I would like to update the `stuff` field to be `Z` where `job._id =` 2 and `content._id = 2`.

I have tried something like this:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection("Jobs");
var query = Query.EQ("_id", jobId);
var job = collection.FindOneAs<Job>(query);

var con = job.content.FirstOrDefault(x => x._id == contentIndex);
if (con != null) con.stuff = "Z";
collection.Save(job);
```

So how use a single query something like this to update the nested doc?

```
collection.Update(Query.EQ("content._id", contentIndex), Update.Set("content.$.stuff", "Z"));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the shell, you could use the [positional](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator and update the element using a query like this:

```js
db.jobs.update({"_id": 2, "content._id":2}, {"content.$.stuff", "Z"});
```

The same query can be translated to C# (which I'm not familiar with).

Comment: This is shell command, I guess user is interested in C# code.